# ASP.NET Change of gridview UPDATE statement after TemplateEditing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET Update GridView with Dropdownlist control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396493/asp-net-update-gridview-with-dropdownlist-control)

I am using VS2005 C#.

Currently I have a GridView, and I have changed one of my GridView control to my column name `Gender`, from the default `TextBox` to a `DropDownList`, which I gave the `ID` of the control to `GenderList`, and it contains 2 values, *M* and *F*.

I have a default update statement which is able to update the GridView after `edit`, which is the following:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString=
"<%$ ConnectionStrings:SODConnectionString %>" UpdateCommand="UPDATE 
[UserMasterData] SET [Name] = @Name, [Age] = @Age, [ContactNo]=@ContactNo,
 [Address]=@Address, [Gender]=@Gender"/>
```

The above UPDATE query works perfectly, and now I have changed my `Gender` *textbox* to a *dropdownlist*, the `UPDATE` query gave me an error which says:

`Must declare the scalar variable "@Gender".`

I assume the UPDATE query couldn't find the value from my `Gender` column.

I tried to modify the UPDATE query to `@GenderList`, but it did not work as well.

Anyone knows what I should do do the UPDATE query so that my UPDATE query can find the value from my `GenderList` dropdownlist in my `Gender` column?

Thank you.

---

Below is my previous `Gender` column with a textbox control:

```
                <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Gender" 
                DataField="Gender" 
                SortExpression="Gender"></asp:BoundField>
```

Below is my `Gender` with the dropdownlist control:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" >
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="GenderList" runat="server" Width="50px" >
                <asp:ListItem>M</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
```

---

EDIT:

Tried implementing  `RowDatBound` and `onRowUpdating`:

---

`RowDatBound`

---

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView dRowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DropDownList OriginalRiskList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("GenderList");
            OriginalRiskList.SelectedValue = dRowView[2].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

---

`RowUpdating`.aspx.cs

---

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

DropDownList genderSelect =(DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("GenderList");

SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Gender"].DefaultValue = 
genderSelect.SelectedValue; --> error says not set to an instance of an object

}
```

---

I am still not able to update my `Gender` column. Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Need some help here, thank you..