# Update GridView with Dropdownlist control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am using VS2005 C#.

Currently I have a GridView, and I have changed one of my GridView control to my column name `Gender`, from the default `TextBox` to a `DropDownList`, which I gave the `ID` of the control to `GenderList`, and it contains 2 values, *M* and *F*.

I have a default update statement which is able to update the GridView after `edit`, which is the following:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString=
"<%$ ConnectionStrings:SODConnectionString %>" UpdateCommand="UPDATE 
[UserMasterData] SET [Name] = @Name, [Age] = @Age, [ContactNo]=@ContactNo,
 [Address]=@Address, [Gender]=@Gender"/>
```

The above UPDATE query works perfectly, and now I have changed my `Gender` *textbox* to a *dropdownlist*, the `UPDATE` query gave me an error which says:

`Must declare the scalar variable "@Gender".`

I assume the UPDATE query couldn't find the value from my `Gender` column.

I tried to modify the UPDATE query to `@GenderList`, but it did not work as well.

Anyone knows what I should do do the UPDATE query so that my UPDATE query can find the value from my `GenderList` dropdownlist in my `Gender` column?

Thank you.

---

Below is my previous `Gender` column with a textbox control:

```
                <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Gender" 
                DataField="Gender" 
                SortExpression="Gender"></asp:BoundField>
```

Below is my `Gender` with the dropdownlist control:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" >
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="GenderList" runat="server" Width="50px" >
                <asp:ListItem>M</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
```

---

EDIT:

Tried implementing  `RowDatBound` and `onRowUpdating`:

---

`RowDatBound`

---

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView dRowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DropDownList genderList= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("GenderList");
            genderList.SelectedValue = dRowView[2].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

---

`RowUpdating`.aspx.cs

---

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

DropDownList genderSelect =(DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("GenderList");

SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["Gender"].DefaultValue = 
genderSelect.SelectedValue; --> error says not set to an instance of an object

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395365/asp-net-change-of-gridview-update-statement-after-templateediting/8395849#8395849 same question with one more new acc ??? don ask question same question with new thread,  even Your the same User http://stackoverflow.com/users/872370/ruihao

Comment: Please don't create new accounts and ask the same exact question again.  Also, ***please*** stop prefacing your questions with "asp.net".  There is no need to add tags to your title; we have a tag system that works perfectly well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SqlDataSource and updating data via it then all you have to do is to set 2 way binding for the dropdownlist GenderList.

You can set this via the designer or directly in source also

```
 <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="GenderList" runat="server" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem>M</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
```

notice that here 2 way binding is being used.

Comment: How can I dynamically populate this drop down ? Should I do it in every RowDataBound event ?
And how do I populate the <ItemTemplate> with the textual value (and not the "Gender" value) ?   thx

Answer (score 0):

you need to use its selected value property, dropdown list is collection of values, but you are assigning a scalar value to your update statements. 
You have to check when its in update mode, you need to get selected item value of dropdown list and use that value as parameter for update statements.
[Editing with Dropdownlist in gridview](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/08/radiobuttonlist-dropdown-gridview-edit.html)

to check its in edit mode or not use like this in RowDataBound Event

```
if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
```

Comment: thanks for the link. i tried and i met some error, pointing out that my reference is not set to an object instance.

Comment: check you instantiated your objects properly or not